# Download Large File from Azure Blob Storage, process it and send back to the Client

Tags: c#, streaming, azure-blob-storage

I have the following request flow where the customer can request to download a CSV file from the Server. The issue is that the blob file is too large and the customer has to wait a lot longer before the actual download starts (the customer thinks that there is some issue and closes the browser). How can the download be made more efficient using streams?
Current sequence is as below:

**Request Sequence:**

1. Client clicks the download button from the browser.
2. Backend receives the request.
3. Backend Server Downloads the Blob from the Azure Storage Account.
4. There is some custom processing that needs to be done.
5. Once the processing is completed, start sending the response back to the client.

Now the issue is that while using the [DownloadTo(Stream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadto?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_DownloadTo_System_IO_Stream_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_Azure_Storage_StorageTransferOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) function of BlobBaseClient, the file is entirely downloaded to memory before I could do anything.
How can I download the blob file in chunks, do the processing and start sending it to the customer?

**Part of Download Controller:**

```
        var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "customer-file.csv",
            CreationDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        };
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
        var result = blobService.DownloadAndProcessContent();
        foreach (var line in result)
        {
            yield return line ;
        }
        Response.BodyWriter.FlushAsync();
```

**Part of DownloadAndProcessContent Function:**

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var blob = container.GetAppendBlobClient(blobName);
        blob.DownloadTo(stream);
        // Processing is done on the Blob Data
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string currentLine= streamReader.ReadLine();
            // process the line.
            string processDataLine = ProcessData(currentLine);
            yield return processDataLine;
        }
```

Comment: The fact your solution relies on cloud sourced CSV files is likely the bigger issue and points to a bigger architectural problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using built-in method [OpenRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.openread?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_OpenRead_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobOpenReadOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) so you can apply the `StreamReader` directly to the blob stream without needing a `MemoryStream` in the middle? This should give you a way process line-by-line as you do in the loop.
Also note it's recommended to take the async-await approach [all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way) so your controller code (made async) would be much more scalable by not blocking on I/O turning the .Net thread-pool into a bottleneck for handling concurrent requests to your API.

This answer doesn't address returning an HTTP response with streaming, that's separate from streaming a downloaded blob.